# Does Hibernate make sense without Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Some years ago I started "studying" and working with JAVA (I gotta say that I am an embedded developer, so I mostly work in C and C++).

Receptly I have started working with Databases so I stumbled on Hibernate. I read couple of starting guides and books about the topic and started to play around with some small projects.

Surfing on the Internet (Stackoverflow included) I only have seen projects that include Hibernate/JPA + Spring *[+ Struts]*.

I am designing a quite big personal project. I wanted to do it "step by step" in order to learn all parts that it implies: DB, Hibernate (I wanted to use first hbm.xml and then Annotations), make an easy standalone swing application, and then use Spring + web page.

Probably my question is a little stupid but, I will ask it anyway

**Does Hibernate make sense without Spring?**

Should I keep playing a little longer with Hibernate while I read up on Spring and then develope the project using both technologies?

My only goal in this project is to learn. Nothing more, nothing less. I do not care about the effort.

Thanks so much for your opinions! I appreciate!

Comment: Of course it does. Hibernate is an ORM framework. It does not require Spring in any way.

Comment: The two are often used together, but in some cases Hibernate can be used perfectly sensibly without spring yes - a project I'm working on at the moment does just that (in a desktop application.)

Comment: For example you can use Hibernate in a GWT project with only marginal server-side back-end apart from entity management.

Comment: Both are stronger technology in there field but you can merge them too.

Comment: Or just use JPA (implemented by Hibernate or anything else) in a java EE application server (e.g. Wildfly). You'll get all "goodies" that Spring would provide, but in a standard way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Hibernate make sense without Spring but it will make more sense with Spring :)

As you have already studied Hibernate, you know about it so let me tell you that Spring will make your life more easier mainly because of DI and it also have Hibernate support classes for doing common functions, transaction management.

I suggest you to do both together because without Spring you will be learning obsolete Hibernate Design, for example using Service Locator etc.

Note : You will find learning Spring way much easier as compared to Hibernate :)

Comment: Or use it (or better, JPA) in any Java EE container and get all DI, JAX-RS, whatever you need for free.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a pressing reason to do your database work first, I would suggest taking a different approach and learning Spring core before you dive into Hibernate.  This is what I did way back when I learned both, and it was very effective for me.

As another answer mentions, Spring is (probably) easier to learn than Hibernate, and you will probably end up with a "cleaner" project as a result of using Spring since using the framework encourages the use of a lot of best practices in Java.  Since you're learning Java, that's a big plus.

Once you get those practices down, you can move into Spring/Hibernate integration and tackle that, but you'll probably find it a lot easier.